# Pull a specific file/directory from a remote repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

Coming unstuck figuring this one out.

How do you obtain a set of files from a specific repository and merge them into your current working directory. The difficulty I'm finding is I want to obtain files from a certain tagged release of the repository.

I've tried adding the remote repository and fetching the most up to date but I'm flooded with every single tag and then I'm unsure how to 'select' the files I want to replace with my own.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this remote repository the same as the repo in which your target branch is located?  What do you mean by "merge" the files?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen yes it's the same (would it matter if the repo was different?)  - and essentially I mean overwrite my local files with the files from the remote repo.

Comment: I am marking duplicate, because AFAIK the accepted answer in the duplicate link should directly solve your problem.  If not, then drop a comment here and someone may reopen your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's a completely different question. here he's asking how to pull a specific file in the 'duplicate link' he's asking how to revert a file to a specific version. how is it the same in any possible way?